# PHP Login script problems with check if user banned

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm getting errors with the PHP login script I am using on my site.

I wanted to add code which checks if the user is banned when he/she logs in.

But for some reason(s), it's not working properly; it always outputs "You are banned," even if the ban field/attribute contains on "n" for false in the MySQL "users" table.

I've tried fixing the code, but I still get errors. This is my code:

```
$bancheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ban = '".$_POST['username']."'" ) or die(mysql_error());
$ban = mysql_fetch_array($bancheck);    

if ($ban = 'y') {
  die('You are banned...');
}
```

The MySQL field which I've to check against is called "ban" and value is either "y" for "true," or "n" for "false."

Comment: Haha an opportunity for a [little bobby tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) link!

Comment: Also, when will `$ban` ever be equal to `y`? `$ban` appears to be an array...

Comment: I'm addition to the answers, are you sure you want to check your `ban` column against the username and not `y`?

Comment: This line is wrong `if ($ban = 'y') {{` first, `$ban == 'y'`. Second, double `{{` are incorrect because I can't see the close bracket for the first bracket.

Comment: @downvoter give the guy a chance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1: Should be a comparison, not an assignment.

This line is incorrect:

```
if ($ban = 'y') {{
```

It should be:

```
if ($ban == 'y') {
```

I'm assuming there's an extra brace there by accident also.

---

#### 2: SQL injection

You should not pass your string straight `from $_POST` into your MySql as you are vulnerable to SQL injection. You should escape it like so:

```
$bancheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ban = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."'" )or die(mysql_error());
```

---

#### 3: Ban != user

You should not compare `ban` to the username passed in via the form anyway, as ban will either hold the string 'y' or 'n'. You should compare the username (passed in) to the approriate username field in your database table. Like so:

```
$bancheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username'])."'" )or die(mysql_error());
```

---

#### 4: Proper iteration & comparison

Instead of the `mysql_fetch_array()` function I'd use the `mysql_fetch_assoc()` function because it returns an [associative array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php).

This will return an associative array for each row returned (contained in the MySql resource `$bancheck`) so you need to iterative through them (even though it should only return one array) like so:

```
while($ROW = mysql_fetch_assoc($bancheck))
{
    if('y' == $ROW['ban']) {

        die('You are banned...');
    
    }
}
```

But I'd add in some more code just to help with any other problems:

```
$count = mysql_num_rows($bancheck);
if($count > 1)
{
    die('More than one user with that username');    
}
elseif($count > 0)
{
    while($ROW = mysql_fetch_assoc($bancheck))
    {
        if('y' == $ROW['ban']) {

            die('You are banned...');
        
        }
    }
}
else //i.e. $count<=0
{
    die('No users with that username');
}
```

Comment: Also note, this is why many devs prefer to put the static value first and the variable second: `if ('y' == $ban)` This way, if they accidentally use a single equals instead of a double, it generates a compile error.

Comment: But $ban is an array from `mysql_fetch_array($bancheck);`

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($ban = 'y') {{
```

should be

```
if ($ban == 'y') {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$bancheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ban = '".$_POST['username']."'" )or die(mysql_error());
```

this i think should be:

```
$bancheck = mysql_query("SELECT ban FROM users WHERE username = '".$_POST['username']."'" )or die(mysql_error());
```

if the column for username is called "username"

Comment: Should not. It is Mysql Injection vulnerable.

Comment: It is Mysql Injection vulnerable but the answer can also be read as pointing out the wrong column is being checked, which it does appear to be. Certainly the code as posted has about 3 errors in of which that is one.

Comment: as @James pointed out i was just pointing out that the search was wrong, but you are absolutely right in that it is very vulnerable to injection. I hear prepared statements goes a long way :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Learn about SQL injection hacker attacks. Go and do it now.
2. Are you checking the
   right column in your inital statement? Should it not be "SELECT *
   FROM users WHERE username =" or whatever? (as tveitan says)
3. $ban is an array. You need
   $ban['ban'] instead to get the ban column.  (as  animuson says)
4. For comparison == not = (as adam says)

Comment: yeah, I assumed that was to do with how the code snippet had been copied and pasted but I should have highlighted that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$bancheck = mysql_query("SELECT banned FROM users WHERE username = '". mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) ."'") or die(mysql_error());
$ban = mysql_fetch_array($bancheck);    

if($ban['banned'] == 'y') {
    die('You are banned...');
}
```

Where `banned` (`$ban['banned']`) are your field with 'y' or 'n'.
But check the `$_POST['username']` for mysql injection tries. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 0):

To recap and expand, the assignment/comparison and the wrong column in the SQL WHERE clause are mistakes anyone will make from one time to another. The code snippet is still broken, though.

[The PHP documentation for mysql_fetch_array](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) states that the function returns an array containing the row where the databases internal pointer, not just a single value.

I'd do something like this

```
$username = do_some_injection_checking_or_escaping($_POST['username']);
$bancheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."' AND ban='y';") or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($bancheck) == 1) {
    die('You are banned...');
}
```

This is a good method if you just need to check something is there a certain number of times and you don't need the data.

Comment: You don't need the `$ban = mysql_fetch_array($bancheck);` in this case. Good solution too.

Comment: Hehe I just saw that when editing something else. And thank you :)